# Trouble understanding the notation for the gradient of vector field...

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, tensors

I understand that the gradient of a vector field is a rank two tensor.  I am having trouble understanding the RHS of the below equation for the stress field generated in a liquid crystal:

$$ \sigma_{\alpha\beta}^{elastic} = - \kappa \partial_{\alpha}P_{\gamma}\partial_{\beta}P_{\gamma} $$

Here, $\kappa$ is a scalar and $P$ is a vector field.

Is $\partial_{\alpha}P_{\gamma}\partial_{\beta}P_{\gamma}$ equivalent to $\nabla \vec{P}$ (a rank two tensor) multiplied by $(\nabla \vec{P})^T$?  Here, the multiplication would be like a matrix multiplication.  Or, am I completely misreading this...?

Thanks!

Comment: The most reasonable assumption is that those chrystalographs are summing over $\gamma.$ If chrystalographs don't have the urge to write chrystal clear papers, who then?

Comment: *chrystallographers